# hardhat does not find artifact when deploying

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

After initializing with `$ npx hardhat` I am having trouble when deploying using hardhat.

```
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "<contract_name>" not found.
```

I can compile my contract with no errors
`$ npx hardhat compile`, however when I try to deploy it using the deploy script I get the error:

```
$nnpx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeb

HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "<contract_name>" not found.
```

In my `hardhat.config.js` I have the paths:

```
        sources: "./contracts",
        artifacts: "./artifacts",
        cache: "./cache"
    },
```

and in the deploy script `deploy.js` I have

```
    const NFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("contract");
    const nft = await NFT.deploy();

    await nft.deployed();
```

and I have te contract saved in `contracts/contract.sol`.

I don't know which is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I managed to find out what was wrong.
The contract filename and the contract definition were different.
I don't know if the filename of the contract and the contract definition has to be the same.

In `contracts/contract.sol` I have:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

imports ...

contract NTFContract is ERC1155, Ownable {...
}
```

After renaming `contracts/contract.sol --> contracts/NTFContract.sol` I don't have this problem anymore and I am able to deploy it correctly.

I still wonder which is the convention in general for solidity and for hardhat.

edit: apparently contract name matching the filename is a [convention](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/style-guide.html#contract-and-library-names)

Answer (score 1):

if you compiled with a different filename previously, it could be defunct cache data causing the error. you could try rebuilding the cache to clear the problem

```
$ npx hardhat clean ; npx hardhat compile
```

quick and easy so worth a try

Answer (score 0):

"After renaming contracts/contract.sol --> contracts/NTFContract.sol I have no more this problem and I am able to deploy it correctly."

Make sure that the file name is changed in the cache/solidity-files-cache.json as well, otherwise the error will persist even after renamining.